# Start Storyboard when TextBox Text changed via binding

Tags: xaml, triggers, textbox, storyboard, uwp

I'm writing an Universal App for Windows (W10 + WP10) and wanted to start a Storyboard, when then displayed Text, which is a binding, changed.

First Try:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ASH}">
 <TextBox.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated" >
   <BeginStoryboard >
    <Storyboard>
     <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="Red" To="Transparent" Duration="0:1:0" />
    </Storyboard>
   </BeginStoryboard>
  </EventTrigger>
 </TextBox.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Second Try:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ASH}">
 <TextBox.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.DataContextChanged" >
   <BeginStoryboard >
    <Storyboard>
     <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="Red" To="Transparent" Duration="0:1:0" />
    </Storyboard>
   </BeginStoryboard>
  </EventTrigger>
 </TextBox.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Who has an idee, how to start the storyboard?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting XAML only and have the behaviors package installed? You could use the ControlStoryboardAction behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`EventTrigger` is not supported in a UWP app, as @Chris W. said, if you want to do this using XAML only, you could ues the ControlStoryboardAction behavior.

But you must add `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed` package to your app’s references before you use it. To add this references, you can get it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed).

You can also do this with `x:Bind` and code behind. I wrote a sample below, the first `TextBox` named "txt" uses `x:Bind`, and the second `TextBox` named "DataTriggerTB" uses ControlStoryboardAction behavior.

XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="StoryBoardApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:StoryBoardApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" 
    xmlns:Interactions="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:Media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardSample">
            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:3" To="Transparent" From="Red"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                Storyboard.TargetName="DataTriggerTB" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="std" x:Name="std" >
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="brush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" From="Red" To="Transparent" Duration="0:0:3" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt"  Text="{x:Bind text, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="300" Height="200" >
            <TextBox.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="brush"/>
            </TextBox.Background>
        </TextBox>


        <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="300" Height="200" x:Name="DataTriggerTB">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=DataTriggerTB}" ComparisonCondition="NotEqual" Value="{Binding Text, ElementName=DataTriggerTB}">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardSample}" />
                </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

code behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();                       
    }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _text;

        public string text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _text)
                {
                    _text = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                this.std.Begin();
            }
        }
}
```

But if you are using a MVVM pattern, `this.std.Begin();` in the `x:Bind` method will break MVVM pattern.